# Searching in parameter space for a given number of solutions

Tags: equation-solving

I have this problem : I have some function g[a,b;x], where a,b are parameters and x is a variable. I know (graphically) that an equation g[a,b;x]=0 has zero, one or two solutions. 
I want to keep 'a' fixed and find a such 'b' (as a function of 'a') that the number of solutions will be equal to one.

How can I do this? In other words I want to do something like

```
Solve[{Number of solutions{Solve[g[a,b,x]==0,x]}==1,b]
```

(a physical example : for a rotating black hole we have a (00) metric tensor component g_00[M,J;r]. Usually there are two horizons (r_+,r_-) where g_00=0. I want to keep M fixed and search for such J that r_+=r_-, so there is only one horizon (I know this happens for J=0, but I want to compute it using Mathematica).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes the following idea works `eq[x_] := a x^2 + b x + c; Solve[Equal @@ (x /. Solve[eq[x] == 1, x])]`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @belisarius comment except I understood your question to ask for b in terms of a. If the equaton can be solved symbolically, equate the two solutions and solve the resulting equation for b. For example

```
eqn = a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0;

sol = Solve[Equal @@ (x /. Solve[eqn, x]), b]
```

> {{b -> -2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]}, {b -> 2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]}}